# Number of squares and rectangles in a box

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

[image]

Consider the above picture .
Total number of rectangles and squares can be determined using 
$\binom m2\binom n2$ ,where $m$ represents number of lines in horizontal and $n$ represents the same but in vertical. that is I'm selecting $2$ lines out of $m$ horizontal lines and another $2$ out of $n$ vertical lines.
So $\binom 32\binom 52=30$ (squares+rectangles).
My question is "how to get only the number of squares formed by that diagram".

Is it possible to get?

Comment: Thank u boss!! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $d=\min(m,n)$. Then a square can have side length up to $d-1$, and a square of side length $a$ can be in $m-a$ horizontal positions and in $n-a$ vertical positions, so in total there are

$$
\sum_{a=1}^{d-1}(m-a)(n-a)=\frac16(d-1)(2d^2-d(3m+3n+1)+6mn)=\frac16(d-1)(3mn-d(d+1))
$$

squares.

Comment: can you explain the expansion of above formula?

Comment: @BrijRajKishore: The first equality is based on $\sum1=d-1$, $\sum a=\frac12d(d-1)$, $\sum a^2=\frac16d(d-1)(2d-1)$. To obtain the second equality, note that $\min(m,n)(3m+3n)=\min(m,n)^2+3mn$.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it. I mean here the first equalities you have stated above are pretty straightforward formulas. But I didn't understand how $ \sum_{a=1}^{d-1}(m-a)(n-a) $ equates to $ \frac16(d-1)(2d^2-d(3m+3n+1)+6mn)$. Second, I think that $ \min(m,n)(3m+3n) $ should be $ 3 \times \min(m,n)^2+3mn$

Comment: @BrijRajKishore: Ah, sorry, you're right about the second one. That's just an error in the comment, though; the answer works out because $2d^2-3d^2=-d^2$. For the first one, you just need to apply the "pretty straightforward formulas":

\begin{eqnarray*}
mn(d-1) -(m+n)\frac12d(d-1)+\frac16d(d-1)(2d-1)&=&\frac16(d-1)\left(6mn-3(m+n)d+d(2d-1)\right)\\&=&\frac16(d-1)(2d^2-d(3m+3n+1)+6mn)\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: My bad I was not taking m, n as constant terms. Now I get it. Thanks a lot. I really appreciate the time you have given for me otherwise users with such reputation are the fastest in downvoting rather than explaining patiently even after such a long time. Again, thanks a lot

Comment: @BrijRajKishore: You're welcome :-)

Answer (score 1):

Each square is characterized by its **unique** bottom-right-corner point. See figure below.

[image]

Thus, for a lattice with $m \times n$ points,

for the $ 1 \times 1$ square, there are $(m -1) \times (n-1)$; (See the square black dots.)

for the $ 2 \times 2$ square, there are $(m -2) \times (n-2)$; (See the red over black dots.)

For the $ 3 \times 3$ square, there are $(m -3) \times (n-3)$; (See the green oven (the red over black) dots.)

Counting continues until one of the factors is 0.

Total = (m-1)(n – 1) + (m – 2)(n -2) + (m – 3)(n – 3) + ….